# Binding from combobox to textbox without using SelectionChanged event

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding

I am binding ID to a combobox, name to a textbox.  When I change combobox value, the textbox should change too. But not using the SelectionChanged event of combobox But just using binding.
Ex: combobox : ID001, textbox : name1
combobox change to: ID002, textbox :name 2.
Thanks.

Comment: provide some XAML of what you do have and I will gladly help.

Comment: Hi. I got it . thanks